# Minium Upgrade Jqgrid? How?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, upgrade

I want to update to last version of jqgrid mainly to can use rowattr, because my huge project are in "jqGrid 4.2.0" and I need to apply styles in every differents rows. My question is which file/s I have to replace to use this option? I dont want change all the files if its possible to can avoid problems with some options of my old version..

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to not partially replace any files/parts of files otherwise you would likely experience oddities at some point. Do a parallel install, change the js path to point to the new installation and see if that breaks anything.

Comment: Just found the [git commit](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ead2534d3f87634f81b7af4203fe21372fa8aa6e) that implemented `rowattr`, feel free to implement this.

Comment: Hi Sascha, how can i do this? Sorry but i dont know how do it or if you can tell me wich code of this git commit is, I really appreciate it! Is deleting the red code and add the green? Thanks again.

Comment: It's not that easy, you would be lucky if your grid.base.js would be the same version as the git version is. You would first have to compare the [raw version](https://raw.github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/ead2534d3f87634f81b7af4203fe21372fa8aa6e/js/grid.base.js) with your version and if they are similar, you can try removing and adding the highlighted lines from the git push. Anyway, why don't you first try to update your complete version?

Comment: I will try it, but i would like to only implements rowattr event if is possible instead to upgrade all the plugin!

Comment: What you could try to do is download the [three base components](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6), make a backup of your current 4.2.0 installation and overwrite the files with the newly downloaded files. Clear your browser cache, reload the page and check if any errors are shown or the grid behaves different than before. This might work, inter-version releases are most likely downwards compatible so the 4.2 plugins may work without changes.

Comment: ITs very strange, I only have `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and `grid.subgrid.js` and the `ui.jqgrid.css` in the project, with jquery 1.4.3! I have replaced the min and subgrid files but it dont show me any background color using rowattr event..I have overwrite the old files, and clean the cache..And dont work..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22116/discussion-between-sascham78-and-bombai)

Comment: Thanks for all support Sascha! Perfect! We have fixed the issue!